# Calculating the number of rows between occurrences of a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

First of all, I am not sure I am phrasing this problem right, that's probably why I didn't find a solution to it online.

I have an example dataframe, generated with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = list(np.arange(24)) * 2
data2 = ['A'] * 24 + ['B'] * 24
data3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(data1, data2, data3), columns=['day', 'group',
                  'value'])

days_with_one = df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.loc[df['value'] == 1,
                          'day'])
```

What I want to do is for each day where the value is "1", find out how many days went by since the last time that value was "1" (for each group seperately).

```
df
Out[49]: 
    day group  value
0     0     A      0
1     1     A      0
2     2     A      0
3     3     A      0
4     4     A      0
5     5     A      1
6     6     A      0
7     7     A      0
8     8     A      0
9     9     A      0
10   10     A      1
11   11     A      0
12   12     A      0
13   13     A      0
14   14     A      0
15   15     A      0
16   16     A      0
17   17     A      0
18   18     A      0
19   19     A      1
20   20     A      0
21   21     A      0
22   22     A      0
23   23     A      0
24    0     B      0
25    1     B      0
26    2     B      0
27    3     B      1
28    4     B      0
29    5     B      0
30    6     B      0
31    7     B      0
32    8     B      0
33    9     B      0
34   10     B      0
35   11     B      0
36   12     B      0
37   13     B      1
38   14     B      0
39   15     B      0
40   16     B      1
41   17     B      0
42   18     B      0
43   19     B      0
44   20     B      1
45   21     B      0
46   22     B      0
47   23     B      0
```

I already reduced the df to only the rows where value is 1. So, the example output would look like this:

```
group  day    days_since
A      5       0
       10      5
       19      9
B      3       0
       13     10
       16      3
       20      4
```

Comment: So what is the expected outcome that you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

First you can create new column for groups by compare by `1` by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html), here if exist some `0` values it means there are some values before first `1` per groups, so filtered by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with first duplicated rows by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and last use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) for difference
per groups with repalce missing values to `0`:

```
df['days_since'] = df['value'].eq(1).groupby(df['group']).cumsum()
mask = ~df.duplicated(['group', 'days_since']) & df['days_since'].ne(0)

df1 = df.loc[mask, ['group','day']].copy()
df1['days_since'] = df1.groupby('group')['day'].diff().fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df1)
   group  day  days_since
5      A    5           0
10     A   10           5
19     A   19           9
27     B    3           0
37     B   13          10
40     B   16           3
44     B   20           4
```

EDIT: Thank you @Henry Yik for simplify answer - you can filter only rows with `1` in `value` and then get differences:

```
mask = df['value'].eq(1)
df1 = df.loc[mask, ['group','day']].copy()
df1['days_since'] = df1.groupby('group')['day'].diff().fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df1)
   group  day  days_since
5      A    5           0
10     A   10           5
19     A   19           9
27     B    3           0
37     B   13          10
40     B   16           3
44     B   20           4
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more straight forward to use `df.loc[df["value"].eq(1)]` and then `groupby` and `diff`?

Comment: @HenryYik - Thank you, you are right, there is already counter column , so you are right.

Comment: @jezrael Why using `copy` here instead can't you use just `drop` to drop the column `value`?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - Because new order of columns is `group` and `day`, so in one filter remove and change order of columns.

Comment: Hmm. makes sense.